# How to use Pivot control in windows Phone 8.1(not Silverlight app)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Can anyone tell me wow to use Pivot control in windows 8.1(not Silverlight app)?
I tried that in code behind and it works when I run the app.

But is there anyway to do it in Xaml?
Help

Comment: Windows or Windows Phone?

Comment: I mean windows phone.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a Pivot App and look at the template they provided for you.  It is pretty easy to  understand if you strip to its bare minimum.

```XAML
<Pivot x:Name="myPivot">
    <PivotItem x:Name="pivot_item1" Header="header1">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="page1"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem x:Name="pivot_item2" Header="header2">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="page2"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </PivotItem>
    <!-- Add more pivot items if your View calls for it -->
</Pivot>
```

[image]

Comment: But My problem happened when I work with universal project. I just found out creating a new page in Shared Project, it can't use the pivot control because pivot control works for windows phone ONLY. So I put my new page(for pivot control use) in Windows.Phone project. Thanks

Comment: @Taedori You're right.  It's kinda difficult working with 3 separate projects (Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1, and a "Shared" project).  Basically, you need to reuse as much as you can but for your Views on the Phone and Windows project make them kinda similar but unique.  Kinda like the Mint.com application for phone/desktop.

Comment: There was a website I bookmarked awhile back that gives you the cross-section for controls that both Win8.1 and WP8.1 supports.  I will add a link in the comments if I ever manage to find it again.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware MSDN docs have a good run through of some controls that map over from WP8 to 8.1 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642486.aspx